# Building Clang on Windows: DiagnosticCommonKinds.inc header doesn't exist

Tags: windows, clang, llvm

I'm trying to build Clang on Windows 8.1 with MS Visual Studio 2013 following instructions at http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html in "Using Visual Studio" section. 
I have checked out **llvm** to `D:\Current\llvm`, **clang** to `D:\Current\llvm\tools\clang`, created `D:\Current\llvm_build` and run `"D:\Program Files (x86)\cmake-3.3.0-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe" -G "Visual Studio 12" ..\llvm` in `llvm_build` directory. 
LLVM.sln and other files are created in `llvm_build` directory without any critical errors. But when I open this solution in Visual Studio and try to compile **clang** project I get errors like this:

```
1>D:\Current\llvm\tools\clang\include\clang/Basic/DiagnosticIDs.h(53): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'clang/Basic/DiagnosticCommonKinds.inc': No such file or directory (D:\Current\llvm\tools\clang\tools\driver\cc1as_main.cpp)
```

Indeed, DiagnosticCommonKinds.inc file is nowhere to be found both in `llvm` and `llvm_build` folders. I suppose it should be generated by CMake during build process but for some reason this doesn't happen and I do not get any meaningful errors. 
Here's output from CMake that I get:

```
-- No build type selected, default to Debug
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Warning: Did not find file Compiler/MSVC-ASM
-- Looking for dirent.h
-- Looking for dirent.h - not found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for errno.h
-- Looking for errno.h - found
-- Looking for execinfo.h
-- Looking for execinfo.h - not found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for limits.h
-- Looking for limits.h - found
-- Looking for link.h
-- Looking for link.h - not found
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h - not found
-- Looking for ndir.h
-- Looking for ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for signal.h
-- Looking for signal.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for sys/dir.h
-- Looking for sys/dir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/mman.h
-- Looking for sys/mman.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/param.h
-- Looking for sys/param.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/uio.h
-- Looking for sys/uio.h - not found
-- Looking for termios.h
-- Looking for termios.h - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for utime.h
-- Looking for utime.h - not found
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h - not found
-- Looking for zlib.h
-- Looking for zlib.h - not found
-- Looking for fenv.h
-- Looking for fenv.h - found
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT - found
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT - found
-- Looking for mach/mach.h
-- Looking for mach/mach.h - not found
-- Looking for mach-o/dyld.h
-- Looking for mach-o/dyld.h - not found
-- Looking for histedit.h
-- Looking for histedit.h - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXXABI_H
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXXABI_H - Failed
-- Looking for arc4random
-- Looking for arc4random - not found
-- Looking for backtrace
-- Looking for backtrace - not found
-- Looking for getpagesize
-- Looking for getpagesize - not found
-- Looking for getrusage
-- Looking for getrusage - not found
-- Looking for setrlimit
-- Looking for setrlimit - not found
-- Looking for isatty
-- Looking for isatty - not found
-- Looking for futimens
-- Looking for futimens - not found
-- Looking for futimes
-- Looking for futimes - not found
-- Looking for mallctl
-- Looking for mallctl - not found
-- Looking for mallinfo
-- Looking for mallinfo - not found
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics - not found
-- Looking for mkdtemp
-- Looking for mkdtemp - not found
-- Looking for mkstemp
-- Looking for mkstemp - not found
-- Looking for mktemp
-- Looking for mktemp - not found
-- Looking for closedir
-- Looking for closedir - not found
-- Looking for opendir
-- Looking for opendir - not found
-- Looking for readdir
-- Looking for readdir - not found
-- Looking for getcwd
-- Looking for getcwd - not found
-- Looking for gettimeofday
-- Looking for gettimeofday - not found
-- Looking for getrlimit
-- Looking for getrlimit - not found
-- Looking for posix_spawn
-- Looking for posix_spawn - not found
-- Looking for pread
-- Looking for pread - not found
-- Looking for realpath
-- Looking for realpath - not found
-- Looking for sbrk
-- Looking for sbrk - not found
-- Looking for srand48
-- Looking for srand48 - not found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - found
-- Looking for strtoq
-- Looking for strtoq - not found
-- Looking for strerror
-- Looking for strerror - found
-- Looking for strerror_r
-- Looking for strerror_r - not found
-- Looking for strerror_s
-- Looking for strerror_s - found
-- Looking for setenv
-- Looking for setenv - not found
-- Looking for _chsize_s
-- Looking for _chsize_s - found
-- Looking for _alloca
-- Looking for _alloca - not found
-- Looking for __alloca
-- Looking for __alloca - not found
-- Looking for __chkstk
-- Looking for __chkstk - not found
-- Looking for __chkstk_ms
-- Looking for __chkstk_ms - not found
-- Looking for ___chkstk
-- Looking for ___chkstk - not found
-- Looking for ___chkstk_ms
-- Looking for ___chkstk_ms - not found
-- Looking for __ashldi3
-- Looking for __ashldi3 - not found
-- Looking for __ashrdi3
-- Looking for __ashrdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __divdi3
-- Looking for __divdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __fixdfdi
-- Looking for __fixdfdi - not found
-- Looking for __fixsfdi
-- Looking for __fixsfdi - not found
-- Looking for __floatdidf
-- Looking for __floatdidf - not found
-- Looking for __lshrdi3
-- Looking for __lshrdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __moddi3
-- Looking for __moddi3 - not found
-- Looking for __udivdi3
-- Looking for __udivdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __umoddi3
-- Looking for __umoddi3 - not found
-- Looking for __main
-- Looking for __main - not found
-- Looking for __cmpdi2
-- Looking for __cmpdi2 - not found
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T - Failed
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS - Success
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_NO_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_NO_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG - Failed
-- Target triple: i686-pc-win32
-- Native target architecture is X86
-- Performing Test HAVE_ELMCB_PCSTR
-- Performing Test HAVE_ELMCB_PCSTR - Success
-- Threads enabled.
-- Doxygen disabled.
-- Sphinx disabled.
-- Go bindings disabled.
-- Could NOT find OCaml (missing:  OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH) 
-- OCaml bindings disabled.
-- Using Debug VC++ CRT: MDd
-- Using Release VC++ CRT: MD
-- Using MinSizeRel VC++ CRT: MD
-- Using RelWithDebInfo VC++ CRT: MD
-- Using Debug VC++ CRT: MDd
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_SIZED_DEALLOC
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_SIZED_DEALLOC - Failed
-- Found PythonInterp: E:/Python27/python.exe (found version "2.7.10") 
-- Constructing LLVMBuild project information
-- LLVMHello ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Targeting AArch64
-- Targeting AMDGPU
-- Targeting ARM
-- Targeting BPF
-- Targeting CppBackend
-- Targeting Hexagon
-- Targeting Mips
-- Targeting MSP430
-- Targeting NVPTX
-- Targeting PowerPC
-- Targeting Sparc
-- Targeting SystemZ
-- Targeting X86
-- Targeting XCore
-- Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing:  LIBXML2_LIBRARIES LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Clang version: 3.8.0
-- SampleAnalyzerPlugin ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- PrintFunctionNames ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- BugpointPasses ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Current/llvm_build
```

Can someone advise how should I fix this problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that instruction at http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html is partially misleading:

> Build the "clang" project for just the compiler driver and front end, or the "ALL_BUILD" project to build everything, including tools.

Is it actually impossible to compile **clang** project in newly created solution, but **ALL_BUILD** project compiles without any problems and generates all necessary files including DiagnosticCommonKinds.inc.